# Micromax A065 - language

Tags: languages

I got a mobile from an Indian friend of mine. The model is Micromax A065 and I would like to install the Greek language and make it the default language.

I tried the following apps with no luck:

1. Locale More Pro
2. MoreLangs
3. Locale Select
4. MoreLocale 2

Is there a way to reset the phone and select the Greek language during the setup?

Answer (score 0):

You can try and use [Language Enabler](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.wanam&hl=en)

Download and open the app. Type the language you want and check mark it. Then press on that "3 dot" button on top right and select `Enable Languages`. See if this works. Ofcourse there are other ways too, but try the simplest one first. You need to be rooted if you are above android 4.2.